# distribute accumulated working hours through days

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have Date time when engine has started working and how long was it working. but sometimes it can work more than 24  Hours.

if it worked for 28 Hours on the starting date i will have record

```
Name          started_working    Finished working     hours_worked 
obj-00123     07/02/2018 13:30   08/02/2018 17:30     28
```

I need to to have record that will show that engine has worked for 10:30 in 07 and 17:30 in 08.

```
Name          started_working    Finished working     hours_worked 
obj-00123     07/02/2018 13:30   07/02/2018 00:00     10:30 
obj-00123     07/02/2018 13:30   08/02/2018 17:30     17:30
```

or something like that.  I don't have any idea how can i get this done. can you give me some clues. i dont ask for writing code if its not too easy.

thank you

[image]

Comment: Did you mean 28 hours in the 3rd line of the question, and not 26 as written?

Comment: Yes 28 Hours. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your sample data working hours may be more than several days. In this case you need to use tally table or recursive CTE. I have used recursive CTE since it's easier to handle result fields. Also there are two columns in result named `started_working` and `started_working2`. `started_working` is from your expected output, but I believe you need `started_working2` column

```
declare @T as table (
    Name varchar(100)
    , started_working datetime
    , finished_working datetime
    --, hours_worked int
)

insert into @T
values 
    ('obj-00123', '20180207 13:30', '20180208 17:30')
    , ('obj-00123', '20180208 19:00', '20180209 05:00')
    , ('obj-00123', '20180209 19:00', '20180209 22:00')
    , ('obj-00123', '20180210 19:00', '20180213 22:00')

;with rcte as (
    select
        *, started_working2 = started_working
        , next_date = cast(dateadd(dd, 1, started_working) as date), 1 step
    from 
        @T
    union all
    select
        Name, started_working, finished_working
        , cast(next_date as datetime)
        , dateadd(dd, 1, next_date), step + 1
    from
        rcte
    where
        next_date < finished_working
)

select
    Name, started_working, started_working2, finished_working
    , right(replace(str(diff / 60), ' ', 0), 2) + ':' + right(replace(str(diff % 60), ' ', 0), 2) hours_worked
from (
    select
        Name, started_working
        , case 
            when step = 1 then started_working 
            else started_working2 
        end started_working2
        , case 
            when step = max(step) over (partition by Name, started_working) 
            then finished_working else next_date 
        end finished_working
    from
        rcte
) t
cross apply (select datediff(mi, started_working2, finished_working) diff) ca
```

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick for you

```
--Using CTE to show sample data
;WITH cteX( Name,started_working,Finished_working)
AS
(
    SELECT 
        'obj-00123','07/02/2018 13:30','08/02/2018 17:30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'obj-00155','07/02/2018 15:00','07/02/2018 22:30'
)
SELECT
      X.Name
    , X.started_working
    , X.Finished_working
    , HoursWorked = CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, X.started_working, X.Finished_working), 0), 114)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
         T1.Name
        ,T1.started_working
        ,Finished_working   = DATEADD(SECOND,0,DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,-1,T1.started_working),0)) -- Dummy finish time @ Midnight
    FROM
        cteX T1
    WHERE
        DATEDIFF(DAY,T1.started_working,T1.Finished_working) <> 0 --Create a dummy finish time @Midnight when start and end not on same day
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
         T2.Name
        ,started_working    = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,T2.started_working,T2.Finished_working) <> 0
                                    THEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, T2.Finished_working), 0) --Start @ Midnight
                                    ELSE T2.started_working
                              END
        ,T2.Finished_working
    FROM
        cteX T2
) X
ORDER BY
    X.Name, X.started_working
```

OUTPUT

```
Name        started_working         Finished_working        HoursWorked
obj-00123   2018-07-02 13:30:00.000 2018-07-03 00:00:00.000 10:30:00:000
obj-00123   2018-08-02 00:00:00.000 2018-08-02 17:30:00.000 17:30:00:000
obj-00155   2018-07-02 15:00:00.000 2018-07-02 22:30:00.000 07:30:00:000
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach the solution something like this:

```
WITH dynamic_twelths_of_hr_table(datetime2_value) AS
(
    SELECT '2017-01-01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, datetime2_value)
    FROM dynamic_twelths_of_hr_table
    WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, datetime2_value) <= '2019-01-01'
)
,twelths_hr_table AS
(
    SELECT
        DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, datetime2_value), 0) AS date_value
        ,datetime2_value
    FROM dynamic_twelths_of_hr_table
)
,modified_source_table AS
(
    SELECT
        name
        ,objectid
        ,engine_start
        ,ISNULL(engine_stop, GETDATE()) AS engine_stop
        ,IIF(engine_start IS NULL OR engine_stop IS NULL, 1, 0) AS is_still_running
    FROM [YOUR_SOURCE_TABLE]
)
SELECT
    name
    ,objectid
    ,is_still_running
    ,date_value
    ,(COUNT(datetime2_value)/12.0) AS hours_run_on_this_day

FROM
    modified_source_table

LEFT JOIN
    twelths_hr_table AS tht
    ON (tht.datetime2_value BETWEEN engine_start AND engine_stop)

GROUP BY
    name, objectid, is_still_running, date_value

ORDER BY
    name, objectid, is_still_running, date_value
```

Note I haven't tested this code so please excuse any small syntax errors.

I've also baked in an assumption about the range of dates to be considered (these can be widened, or made dynamic based on when the query runs), and it has a 5 minute resolution (based on the fact that, at a glance, I could only see one value in the `engine_stop` column that didn't fall on a 5-minute threshold - so I assume sub-5-minute precision is not required).

Basically what it does is expand each engine row out into 5-minute windows (twelths of an hour), and then simply groups these by day and counts the number of windows per day during which the engine was running.

For currently-running engines, it will calculate how long it has run so far. I trust you can tweak the code to your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

thank you to all. this worked perfectly. it needed slight polishing and recursion needed to be set to 0.

But creating view is a trouble with CTE.

create view mroobjectenginerowkinghoursdeclare as
declare @T as table (
    Name nvarchar(100)
    , OBJECTID varchar(50)
    , started_working datetime
    ,STOPFROM datetime
    ,STARTDATE datetime
    ,STOPDATE datetime
    ,MODIFIEDDATETIME datetime
    ,START_STOP int
    ,STARTDESCRIPTION nvarchar(300)
    ,STOPDESCRIPTION nvarchar(300)
    ,wattage nvarchar (50)
    ,purpose nvarchar(300)
    ,location nvarchar(300)
    ,finished_working datetime
    ,oldDiff int
)

insert into @T
select 
    NAME
    ,OBJECTID
    ,STOPTO
    ,STOPFROM
    ,STARTDATE
    ,STOPDATE
    ,MODIFIEDDATETIME
    ,START_STOP
    ,STARTDESCRIPTION
    ,STOPDESCRIPTION
    ,wattage
    ,purpose
    ,location
    ,next_stopfrom
    ,diff
    FROM [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].[mroobjectengineworkinghours]

;with rcte as (
    select
        *, started_working2 = started_working
        , next_date = cast(dateadd(dd, 1, started_working) as date), 1 step
    from 
        @T
    union all
    select
        Name,OBJECTID, started_working,STOPFROM,STARTDATE,STOPDATE,MODIFIEDDATETIME,START_STOP,STARTDESCRIPTION
    ,STOPDESCRIPTION,wattage
    ,purpose
    ,location, finished_working,oldDiff
        , cast(next_date as datetime)
        , dateadd(dd, 1, next_date), step + 1
    from
        rcte
    where
        next_date < finished_working
)

select
    Name,OBJECTID, started_working,STOPFROM,STARTDATE,STOPDATE,MODIFIEDDATETIME,START_STOP,STARTDESCRIPTION
    ,STOPDESCRIPTION,wattage
    ,purpose
    ,location,oldDiff, started_working2, finished_working
    , right(replace(str(diff / 60), ' ', 0), 2) + ':' + right(replace(str(diff % 60), ' ', 0), 2) hours_worked
from (
    select
        Name,OBJECTID, started_working,STOPFROM,STARTDATE,STOPDATE,MODIFIEDDATETIME,START_STOP,STARTDESCRIPTION
    ,STOPDESCRIPTION,wattage
    ,purpose
    ,location,oldDiff
        , case 
            when step = 1 then started_working 
            else started_working2 
        end started_working2
        , case 
            when step = max(step) over (partition by Name, started_working) 
            then finished_working else next_date 
        end finished_working
    from
        rcte
) t
cross apply (select datediff(mi, started_working2, finished_working) diff) ca
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);